# Make an asterisk red in a required input field (React, Ant Design)

Tags: reactjs, input, antd, required

I am a newbie in programming and need your help. Currently I'm developing my so-called pet project and have faced the challenge. I'm using ReactJS and Ant design for styling. So, the problem is that I want to put a red asterisk inside a required input element as a placeholder (hope I make myself clear). I've found some variants to solve the following problem using pure CSS but I want to use Ant Design components instead. Here is my code for my form:

```
<div className="form-wrapper">
  <Form {...formItemLayout} form={form} name="register" scrollToFirstError onFinish={onFinish}>
    <Title level={2} className="justify-content-center register-title">
      Registration
    </Title>
    <Form.Item
      className="justify-content-center"
      name="name"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please input your nickname!',
          whitespace: true,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Input className="custom-register-input" placeholder="Name *" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
      className="justify-content-center"
      name="fullName"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please input your full name!',
          whitespace: true,
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Input className="custom-register-input" placeholder="Surname *" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
      className="justify-content-center"
      name="email"
      rules={[
        {
          type: 'email',
          message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
        },
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
        },
      ]}
    >
      <Input className="custom-register-input" placeholder="E-mail *" />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
      className="justify-content-center"
      name="password"
      rules={[
        {
          required: true,
          message: 'Please input your password!',
        },
      ]}
      hasFeedback
    >
      <Input.Password className="custom-register-input" placeholder="Password *" />
    </Form.Item>
```

And I have no idea how to implement this task((
I would be grateful for your help!

[here is the idea of an input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgSaZ.png)

Comment: The only way you can accomplish it using JSX instead of pure CSS is by adding a child component in each form item and then styling it. 

Ant Design doesn't have any prop related with it since it isn't related with the design system proposals, but you're free to customize it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the exact answer you want but you can use the suffix props of input to pass an icon and make the color red.

```html
<Form.Item label="Email" name="email" rules={[{ required: true, message: "Please input your email!" }]} style={{ width: "100%" }}>
  <Input suffix={<RandomIcon style={{ color: 'red', }} />} />
</Form.Item>
```

NB: don't forget to replace "RandomIcon" with an asterisk icon.
Hope this helps.